# How to do I make my sprite move when it's instantiated in Unity5?

Tags: unity, c#

Here's the code I currently try to use to move my instantiated sprite:

```
time++;

    if (cow == 1 && time >= wait)
    {
        Cow0Walk();
    }

    if (cow == 2 && time >= wait)
    {
        Cow1Walk();
    }

    if (cow == 3 && time >= wait)
    {
        Cow2Walk();
    }

    if (cow == 4 && time >= wait)
    {
        Cow3Walk();
    }

    if (cow == 5 && time >= wait)
    {
        Cow4Walk();
    }

    if (time >= walkTime)
    {
        wait = rnd.Next(45, 140);
        cow = rnd.Next(1, cowAmount);
        walkTime = rnd.Next(1, 4);
        direction = rnd.Next(1, 4);
    }
```

Heres the one of the walk methods:

```
    void Cow0Walk()
{
    if (time <= walkTime && direction == 1)
    {
        cows[0].transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed);
        cows[0].transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed);
    }

    if (time <= walkTime && direction == 2)
    {
        cows[0].transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed);
        cows[0].transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed);
    }

    if (time <= walkTime && direction == 3)
    {
        cows[0].transform.Translate(Vector2.down * speed);
        cows[0].transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed);
    }

    if (time <= walkTime && direction == 4)
    {
        cows[0].transform.Translate(Vector2.down * speed);
        cows[0].transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using a prefab

I don't know what kind of game it is, but for most cases a good option is to use a prefab for the character movement. You can find it in the standard assets.

#### Making your own

If you still want to make your own movement script, the best option is to add a component called `CharacterController`  to your character, and try to avoid moving the `Transform` component. This is because when you move the `CharacterController`,  it will automatically check for collision.

```
float dx = 1; // desired movement along the x axis
float dz = 1; // desired movement along the z axis
float dy = 1; // desired movement along the y axis

GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move(new Vector3(dx, dy, dz));
```

---

If you still want to use the `Transform`, [you might want to view this similar question, at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120592/how-can-i-make-my-character-move-only-forward-in-unity).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly translate your game object, you should do so with [`Transform.Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html). It is worth noting that we almost *always* call this sort of movement from an `Update` method, and need to account for the time delta between update frames. If we do not, we will get varying speeds, based on the number of `Update` calls our build is currently performing per second.

```
public float speed;

void Update()
{
    MoveInLocalSpace(Vector3.forward);
    // or
    MoveInWorldSpace(Vector3.forward);
}

void MoveInLocalSpace(Vector3 direction)
{
    // Move in direction by a rate of speed * current delta time.
    // We do not need to specifiy that we are moving in local space, as 
    // that is the default.
    transform.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void MoveInWorldSpace(Vector3 direction)
{
    // If we want the direction to be interpreted as world coordinates (and not relative to
    // the actual transform position), we need to specify the world space.
    transform.Translate((direction * speed * Time.deltaTime), Space.World);
}
```

---

Note that in the above mentioned question example, it is unclear why this does not work off the bat. That said, you should be ensure that you are accessing the `Transform` of the actual `GameObject` that you wish to move.